# Flutter - Upload Video to Youtube

Tags: flutter, video-recording, dart-pub

In my app I need the ability to take and upload or save a short 5 to 15 second video. I also need to be able to save the video if the user is offline, and upload it when connected to internet.

I can create the video file with the plugin **image_picker**, I tried to save it to the users gallery using plugin **image_picker_saver** but that seems to only handle images.

So I will probably have to use something like **path_provider** to save it to local storage (again examples of writing files are images as byte data)

When connected is there a way to upload a video to a Youtube account ?
I have read up on some Youtube plugins, but they are geared towards playing videos.

I was thinking of using WebViews to pop up the m.youtube.com/upload page but once you start an upload it goes to the desktop www.youtube.com

Other option to consider is using Firestore as the upload destination when they have a connection, but I would still have to manage offline local storage.

Thank you any help

Edit RE: comments below

Here is what I get when trying to capture a Landscape video on iPhone X with **camera** plugin:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you should use image picker since it can't limit the video to 5 to 15 seconds, instead you should use the camera plugin

Comment: Thanks I hadn't seen that plugin. It has the ability to save the video, set resolution, which should point me in the right direction.

Comment: It seems to only shoot video in Portrait with device in Portrait, or that just a restriction in the extended example ? If I capture in landscape the video is captured rotated in the portrait frame.

Comment: no, I can capture landscape video, before capturing, simply turn your mobile phone to landscape.

Comment: Were you able to get it to upload asynchronously once back online?

Comment: I didn't get that process to start automatically. The user hits a button which Syncs data from SQFlite, and images. It does a bit of a hack check if you are connected to internet:   Future<bool> isConnected() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        print('connected');
        hasInternet = true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
      hasInternet = false;
    }
    return hasInternet;
  }

Comment: In a separate test app I was able to capture video (only in Portrait) using camera plugin that then uploads the video to Firestore

Comment: @DaveLister Have you found a solution how to upload the video on youtube with flutter? Another idea could be to pass through Cloud Function and upload via JS (before on Firebase Storage and after to Youtube?)...

Comment: Hey @DaveLister, were you able to figure out how to upload a video to Youtube from Flutter?

Comment: This should work integrating YouTube API to your Flutter app. Try using [insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method. If this doesn't work, could you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: is there any plug-in or extension of flutter which provides upload video to youtube asynchronously capturing from camera? Thanks in advance.